# Is there a way to interact with an Amazon AWS Windows Server EC2 with .Net Framework through AWS Cloud9?

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-framework-version, aws-cloud9

very green developer here.

AWS Cloud9 only handshakes with an EC2 Linux server, or so it seems, via the AWS documentation. Is there any way to replicate my Windows .Net Framework 4.7/SQL Server ASP.NET MVC 5 application on a Linux EC2 instance so I can interact with AWS Cloud9? Or, even better, am I misunderstanding AWS' documentation and a Windows EC2 instance can be connected to Cloud9 via SSH?

Thanks.

Comment: You can write .net core applications that run on Linux servers.

Comment: Thank you. Found this article helpful if anyone else stumbles across a similar issue. https://www.infoworld.com/article/3237924/development-tools/now-you-can-port-code-from-net-framework-to-net-core.html